# How I can correctly parsing and send "PaReq" parameter required for 3d-secure by swift in IOS?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json, 3d-secure

I write iOS mobile app using cloudpayments.ru
Currently I have big problem, can't pay with 3d-secure.

I successfuly get "PaReq" parameter for paying by this code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, apiURLString, parameters: paramsDictionary, encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers: nil)
                .authenticate(user: _apiPublicID, password: _apiSecret)
                .responseJSON{ response in
                    if (jsonData.object.objectForKey("Model") != nil){
                        if (jsonData["Model"].object.objectForKey("AcsUrl") != nil) && (jsonData["Model"].object.objectForKey("PaReq") != nil){

                            let acsURL  = jsonData["Model"].object.objectForKey("AcsUrl") as! NSString
                            let pareqstr  = jsonData["Model"].object.objectForKey("PaReq") as! NSString
```

But when i try go to AcsUrl with "PaReq" and "MD" parameters

```
var postData = NSMutableData(data: "PaReq=fJxVUn9vgjAQ/SqG/6GFFinmrHFzy/xDYzb3AZpyKomAFpg/Pv1ahTmbNLn32r67e1eYnIv94AdN nVfl2AsD6g2w1FWWl9ux971+94U3kbDeGcTZF+rWoIQF1rXa4iDPxh6nKYuzTPibWG98vonRF6gz nyVUK6UYpyL1JKymn3iU0CWSNk8QAemhVTR6p8pGgtLHl/lScsZDFgPpIBRo5jMpaCIoE4mIGbUL yJ2GUhUo9b5qs4O6FFg2NZAbB7pqy8Fc5JAzID2A1uzlrmkOI0JOp1PQ6l0emBaI44E8ilm1Lqqt zjnP5GI2Pd33G11e55fFbHtZXOd3eZ2OgbgbkKkGZUTDIRXRcBCyEWej2DZ640EVrgAZpbfaOwQH l2T6dPSfAuu5sSPpe+gR4PlQlegeAfmLgTxqfv1wdurGOhRRnsRDxiIeiJCy1BqZpimNQifZ3XGC uXUnTGh4U3QAiFMh3fhIN3kbPf2IXxBBurI=".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&MD=8530327".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    postData.appendData("&TermUrl=https://test.ru".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://acs.alfabank.ru/acs/PAReq")!,
                                      cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.HTTPBody = postData

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                let webView = UIWebView.init(frame: self.view.frame)
                webView.delegate = self
                print("3D Secure here!!!")
                self.view.addSubview(webView)

                webView.loadData(data!, MIMEType: (response?.MIMEType)!,
                    textEncodingName: (response?.textEncodingName)!,
                    baseURL: (response?.URL)!)
            })
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

I have unsecess:(

May be it connected with many specific characters in PaReq field like : **/%\n** spacing and others

Can anybody help me?